# Javascript: uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function for object methods

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, phaser-framework

I make a simple quiz game. Here is some relevan methods that i have inside one object.

But doesn't work. I always get an error within 'rightAnswerGot' function. Console drops
"uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function for object methods" for     this.addVariantsHtml(this.updateCharacter());

```
BasicGame.Game.prototype = {


    actionOnClick: function (button) {
    var log;
    if(button.value==this.char_bubble.text) {

        setTimeout(this.rightAnswerGot,1000);

    } else {
        // wrong

              swoshsound.play();

    }
    console.log(log);
},

 rightAnswerGot: function (){

        this.addVariantsHtml(this.updateCharacter());


    },

 addVariantsHtml: function(id) {

    this.answer = this.getAnswersVariants(id);

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        this.button[i].value = this.answer[i]['trans'];
        this.button[i].char_id = this.answer[i]['id'];
        this.ans_text[i].setText(this.answer[i]['trans']);

    }
},

updateCharacter: function() {
        var i = this.getRandomCharacter();
        console.log("updateCharacter: "+i + " " +this.chars[i]);

        this.char_bubble.setText(this.chars[i].getPath());
        return i;
    }

}
```

The aim is to froze the game for a second, when user choose the right answer, and than go to next question. Any ideas why does it happens?

Thanks

Comment: this.getRandomCharacter is not defined, i guess. At least, it's not defined in the code you've presented. It's the first string of updateCharacter method.

Comment: @VladislavQulin -it is defind, I just didn't write it here, since it is not a relevant issue.
I have 500 lines of the code :)

Comment: Well, can you debug the code? There's a typo hiding somewhere within these two methods, i'm pretty sure.

Comment: @VladislavQulin I just found a solution! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a classic JavaScript scope issue to me. However as you've tagged this question as using Phaser, I would suggest you use a Phaser Timer event to avoid scope problems. Specifically:

`setTimeout(this.rightAnswerGot,1000);`

replace it with:

`this.game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND, this.rightAnswerGot, this);`

Which will create a single 1 second timer that fires only once, calling your function at the end of it. You can use 1000 instead of Phaser.Timer.SECOND of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would image that whats happening is that its trying to call the `this.addVariantsHtml` method, before its calling `this.updateCharacter` and getting the ID.

So your probably expecting that when it runs, for it to be something like:

```
this.addVariantsHtml(1);
```

But its actually trying to run

```
this.addVariantsHtml(this.updateCharacter());
```

So just do this:

```
var id = this.updateCharacter();
this.addVariantsHtml(id);
```

Either that or you need to look into method chaining/piping, which is just complicated and doesnt need to be used for this situation, but is interesting :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work even in this format. The magic is - in some places the combination this.addVariantsHtml(this.updateCharacter()); works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found something that made it work!!

Here is a solution:

```
 actionOnClick: function (button) {
    var log;
    if(button.value==this.char_bubble.text) {
var context=this;
        setTimeout(function() {


  context.addVariantsHtml(context.updateCharacter());


},1000);

    } else {
        // wrong

              swoshsound.play();

    }
    console.log(log);
},
```